# Как избавиться от дублирования компонента в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Недавно начал изучать React, появился вопрос про повторяемые компоненты на странице, у которых отличаются только пропсы. Есть файл App.js, в нём блок menu, куда я пихаю компоненты:

```
    <div className="menu">
      <Card title={"Пепперонни"} image={"/images/pizzaPeperoni.png"} price={120} modalContent={recipe}/>
      <Card title={"Салями"} image={"/images/pizzaSalami.png"} price={99} modalContent={recipe}/>
      <Card title={"Гавайская"}  image={"/images/pizzaGavaiskia.png"} price={81} modalContent={recipe}/>
      <Card title={"Грибная"}  image={"/images/pizzaGribnaia.png"} price={144} modalContent={recipe}/>
      <Card title={"4 сезона"} image={"/images/pizzaFourSesons.png"} price={120} modalContent={recipe}/>
    </div>
```

И сам компонент карточки:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
```

import Modal from "./Modal";

const Card = (props) => {
const [isOpened, setIsOpened] = useState(false);

```
const title = ['Пепперонни', 'Салями', 'Гавайская', 'Грибная', '4 сезона']

return (
    <div className="card">
        <img className="info" src="/images/info.png" alt="info" onClick={() => setIsOpened(true)}/>
        <img src= {props.image} alt="pizza" />
        <div className="aboutPizza">
            <h1>{title.map(i => i)}</h1>
            <div className={"buttons"}>
                <form className="first">
                    <button>20 см</button>
                    <button>25 см</button>
                    <button>30 см</button>
                </form>
                <form className="second">
                    <button>Толстое тесто</button>
                    <button>Тонкое тесто</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <h2>{props.price} BYN</h2>
        </div>
        <Modal isOpened={isOpened} setIsOpened={setIsOpened}/>
    </div>
);
};

export default Card;
```

Допустим, мне нужно добавить на страницу ещё 20 таких карточек. Как сделать это проще и красивее, вместо того, чтобы 20 раз прописывать в классе menu 20 карточек со своими пропсами?

Comment: На код в h1 не обращайте внимание, это попытки решить мою проблему

Comment: обычный цикл. в чем проблема ?

Comment: Я понимаю что необходим цикл, но синтаксис реакта, а точнее jsx очень нов для меня,  слабо понимаю кроме html вёрстки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто прокидывайте данные в цикле

```
data = [{
    title: 'Пепперонни',
    image: '/images/pizzaPeperoni.png',
    price: 200,
    modalContent: recipe,
  },
  {
    title: 'Пепперонни',
    image: '/images/pizzaPeperoni.png',
    price: 200,
    modalContent: recipe,
  }
];

<div className="menu">
{data.map(({...item},index)=>(
  <Card 
      key ={index}
      {...item}
  />
)
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score -1):

лучший вариант, это поместить данные в JSON файл и размапить его единожды

```
    import data from './data.json';

    data.map((item)=>{
      <Card data={data} key={item.id}> />
    })
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]